# Can't reverse proxy Node backend using Nginx

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm working with Angular11 + NodeJS on AWS EC2.

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy using nginx.

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name http://MY-AWS-IP.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/dashboard/frontend/dist/frontangular;
    server_tokens off;
    index index.html index.htm;

location /auth/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
location /groceries/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

node: (running on pm2)

```
... Some stuff
const ports = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use("/groceries", groceryRoutes);
app.use("/auth", loginRoutes);

app.listen(ports, () => console.log(`listening on port ${ports}`));
```

When trying to login @ homepage:

error:

> ```
> POST http://localhost:3000/auth/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> ERROR 
> kd {headers: dd, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/auth/login", ok: false, …}
> error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
> headers: dd {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
> message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/auth/login: 0 Unknown Error"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok: false
> status: 0
> statusText: "Unknown Error"
> url: "http://localhost:3000/auth/login"
> __proto__: wd
> ```

I didn't undertand this reverse proxy at all, I thought I should point my app routes.
Thanks!

Comment: your proxying 80 to local 3000, there is no server for 3000

Comment: I am running my node on 3000, I guess. I am using const ports = process.env.PORT || 3000; and running it on pm2

Comment: sure but Nginx is not listening on 3000, hence the connection refused, you need to remove from your clientside code 3000, and instead just use 80 (or remove idea of ports entirely from clientside)

Answer (score 0):

You just need this much:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name http://MY-AWS-IP.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/dashboard/frontend/dist/frontangular;
    server_tokens off;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }   
}
```

You would need to set up different location blocks only if they are going to be handled by a different server, probably running on a different port.

Comment: Oh, got it! It is still not working, so I probably have other issues, do you have any ideia? Thanks!!

Comment: Is your Node app working properly? Can you cURL it at http://localhost:3000?

Comment: I was running it with sudo, I think it was the reason of 'Conection Refused'. Now I am just 'npm start', and 'curl localhost:3000' returns : {"error":{"message":"Not found"}}. And accessing it from browser, returns this same message at DOM. We are getting there, but still not working :(